# How can i listen an input field for every alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i listen every alphabet which typed into input-field dynamically? For example i would like to listen two input-fields same time and after every entry,take the label "body" and add pre and post chars to it and change the "change me"?

example : pre-chars+body+post-chars (needs to be dynamically)

```
<div style="width:300px;">

   <input type="text" class="form-control" style="float:left; width:100px; margin: 10px; margin-left: 3px;" placeholder="post-Chars"></input> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="float:left; width:100px; margin: 10px; margin-left: 3px;" placeholder="post-Chars"></input>
    <div><label><br>body</br></label></div>
</div>
 <p style="padding:10px;">change me !</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x6ozddg6/

thanks !

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ucbwh7zy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add names to your input and id's to part of your code to identify them easily in jquery:

```
<div style="width:300px;">

   <input type="text" class="form-control" style="float:left; width:100px; margin: 10px; margin-left: 3px;" placeholder="post-Chars" name="pre-text"></input> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="float:left; width:100px; margin: 10px; margin-left: 3px;" placeholder="post-Chars" name="post-text"></input>
    <div><label id="body">body</label></div>
</div>
 <p style="padding:10px;" id="change">change me !</p>
```

Than use jquery to do it... it's very simple:

```
$('input[name="pre-text"]').change(function(){
   $('#change').html($(this).val() + $('#body').html() + $('input[name="post-text"]').val());
});
$('input[name="post-text"]').change(function(){
   $('#change').html($('input[name="pre-text"]').val() + $('#body').html() + $(this).val());
});
```